# How to check a value in joi against a set of values

Tags: joi

```
flag: Joi.number().integer().min(0).max(5).positive().required(),
headId: Joi.string().when('flag',{is:[0,1,2] , then: Joi.string().required(),otherwise:Joi.string()})
```

How to perform this type of validation in Joi?
This way of checking flag value is incorrect.I want to check if flag is between 0-2 and then only headId will be required.

Comment: `is` has to also be a Joi condition, doesn't it? So `is: Joi.number().min(0).max(2)`. Also `.positive()` seems redundant when the values between `0` and `5` are already all positive.

Comment: thanks a lot that worked and indeed it was redundant thanks for that too.